# Действие при нажатии на ячейку в QTable

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, таблицы

Можно ли выполнять какое-то действие при нажатии по ячейке Qtable

Comment: Можно, разрешаю... и просто «`QTable`» не существует со времён qt3...

Comment: Уточните: вы имеете ввиду QTableView?

Comment: `QTableWidget::itemClicked`, `QTableWidget::itemPressed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну самое простое - законектится

```
connect(resultView, SIGNAL(clicked(const QModelIndex &)), this, SLOT(handleOnTableClicked(const QModelIndex &)));
```

где
resultView :

```
QTableView* resultView;
```

И написать мини обработчик -

```
void MainWindow::handleOnTableClicked(const QModelIndex &index) {
  if (index.isValid()) {
    QString cellText = index.data().toString();
    //TODO:
    qDebug() << cellText << "\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: А как подключаться к уже созданной таблице?

Comment: @Dikiy_Tunec connect

Comment: @Dikiy_Tunec, вам нужно почитать теории. Шлее и просто документацию полистать, у Qt она лучшая из того, что я видел.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον документации просто с головой